# How to add 2 rows dynamically in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner in JS and jQuery, and I want to add 2 rows dynamically (the orange one and the row which contains the cols) when I click on a link  (the gray rectangle on the bottom of the page).

Here's a screenshot :

[image]
This is my HTML code :

```
<div class="ajout_prest">
    <p class="txt_ajout">
        <a class="AddResults" href="#">Ajouter une nouvelle prestation</a>
    </p>
    <p class="plus_ajout">
        <a class="AddResults" href="#">+</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

And the JS code :

```
<script>
    $('.AddResults').click(function(){
        var rowNumber = 3;

        // All the cols
        var jourVar = $('<td class="jr_td"><p><input type="text" class="datepicker" /></p><p class="ou">ou</p><p><input type="text" class="datepicker" /></p></td>') ;
        var creneauVar = $('<td class="cr_td"><select><option value="h1">10h30</option><option value="h2">11h30</option></select><select class="cr_td_s2"><option value="h3">10h30</option><option value="h4">11h30</option></select></td>') ;
        var repassageVar = $('<td class="rp_td"><select><option value="h5" SELECTED>2h00</option><option value="h6">3h00</option></select></td>') ;
        var menageVar = $('<td class="mn_td"><select><option value="h7" SELECTED>2h00</option><option value="h8">3h00</option></select></td>') ;
        var totalVar = $('<td class="tt_td"><strong>4h.</strong></td>') ;
        var pttcVar = $('<td class="pttc_td"><strong>88 &#8364;</strong></td>') ;
        var corVar = $('<td class="cor_td"><a href="#"><img src="img/ico/corbeille.png" alt="" width="13" height="13" /></a></td>') ;      

        //Create 2 new rows
        var newTitreRow = $('<tr><td class="bar_td" colspan=7><strong>PRESTATION ' + rowNumber + '</strong></td></tr>') ;
        var newContentRow = $('<tr>' + jourVar + '' + creneauVar + '' + repassageVar + '' + menageVar + '' + totalVar + '' + pttcVar + '' + corVar + ');

        //Append the new row to the body of the #table_prest table
        $('#table_prest tbody').append(newTitreRow);
        $('#table_prest tbody').append(newContentRow);

        //Iterate row number
        rowNumber++;
    });
</script>
```

But of course nothing happens. Do you have any idea about this problem?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript code has at least one error in it:

```
var newContentRow = $('<tr>' + jourVar + '' + creneauVar + '' + repassageVar + '' + menageVar + '' + totalVar + '' + pttcVar + '' + corVar + ');
```

at the end of the concatentation there is an extra + '

it should probalby be:

```
var newContentRow = $('<tr>' + jourVar + '' + creneauVar + '' + repassageVar + '' + menageVar + '' + totalVar + '' + pttcVar + '' + corVar + '</tr>');
```

Edit:

Also I should mention that the rowNumber variable you are using won't iterate upwards each time you click the link as it will reset each time you click.  Either use a global variable for that, or just get the count of rows form the table each time the button is clicked instead if you want to update the Title line with the row number.

Comment: Thank you. It works for the RowNumber variable now, and the first row (the orange one) is added.
But the second one "newContentRow" doesn't appear

Comment: As mentioned in another answer you can't concatentate jQuery objects into a string as you are doing.  Either just get rid of the jQuery objects for the individual cells of the newContentRow and use strings, or just use the .append method instead when adding the cells to the newContentRow. I made a jsFiddle with an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ioncache/6kkfr/3/

Comment: but do you know why the CSS of the "datepicker" (jourVar var) is not applied ??

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is you forgot the last single quote ' in the line below

```
  var newContentRow = $('<tr>' + jourVar + '' + creneauVar + '' + repassageVar + '' + menageVar + '' + totalVar + '' + pttcVar + '' + corVar );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues.

As pointed out, you're missing a closing `'` when concatenating the rows.

But also, you're trying to concatenate jQuery objects instead of strings. You don't need the jQuery objects at all.

Also, you don't need the `+ '' +` between the variable concatenations.

```
var rowNumber = 3;

$('.AddResults').click(function(){

    // Concatenate the cells into a single string
    var cells = 
      '<td class="jr_td"><p><input type="text" class="datepicker" /></p><p class="ou">ou</p><p><input type="text" class="datepicker" /></p></td>' +
      '<td class="cr_td"><select><option value="h1">10h30</option><option value="h2">11h30</option></select><select class="cr_td_s2"><option value="h3">10h30</option><option value="h4">11h30</option></select></td>' +
      '<td class="rp_td"><select><option value="h5" SELECTED>2h00</option><option value="h6">3h00</option></select></td>' +
      '<td class="mn_td"><select><option value="h7" SELECTED>2h00</option><option value="h8">3h00</option></select></td>' +
      '<td class="tt_td"><strong>4h.</strong></td>' +
      '<td class="pttc_td"><strong>88 &#8364;</strong></td>' +
      '<td class="cor_td"><a href="#"><img src="img/ico/corbeille.png" alt="" width="13" height="13" /></a></td>'

    // Create 2 new rows
    var newTitreRow = '<tr><td class="bar_td" colspan=7><strong>PRESTATION ' + rowNumber + '</strong></td></tr>'
    var newContentRow = '<tr>' + cells + '<tr>'

    //Append the new row to the body of the #table_prest table
    $('#table_prest tbody').append(newTitreRow + newContentRow);

    //Iterate row number
    rowNumber++;
});
```